# How to commit code to GitHub on Android through termux app

Tags: github, termux

Please I would appreciate if anyone can drop a direct link to the termux commands used to create repos,commit code and delete them on GitHub through termux terminal,all I have seen through numerous Google searches are only how to install them,I also don't know how to navigate to a certain file or directory.

Comment: just [learn git](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/common-git-commands.html) , commands are same

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to install git in termux `pkg install git` . then go to the directory where your code have with `cd <name of your directory>`

If you want to create a git repository use `git init`.

then add the files to git
`git add <file name>` **OR** add all files in the directory `git add .`

> First commit after installing git you have to specify who you are
> `git config --global user.name "<Your Name>"`
> `git config --global user.email "<your_email@whatever.com>"`

then commit the code with
`git commit -m "<commit message>"`

> commit message is what changes you done in this commit

you have to create a reposityory in github [github.com/new](https://github.com/new)
and add github reposityory url to git `git remote add origin https://github.com/<github username>/<github repository name>.git`

then push the repository to github. `git push -u origin master`

> `-u` means seting upstream as default. after that just `git push`

have some reference of tutorials about git
[learnxinyminutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/git/), [githowto](https://githowto.com/)

Comment: this is a very valuable reply. thx @Django